# I need to reverse some file changes I just made

Tags: permissions, terminal

I was following someone's answer and they said to:

```
user@User-pc ~ $ cd /var/lib/apt
user@User-pc /var/lib/apt $ sudo mv lists lists.old
user@User-pc /var/lib/apt $ sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
```

What commands can I do to completely undo these operations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd /var/lib/apt
```

Removing the new `lists/partial` structure:

```
sudo rmdir lists/partial
sudo rmdir lists
```

These commands will complain if the directories are not empty.  If that happens, you have likely done something else that you are not showing.

There should now be no thing with the name `lists` in the current directory.

Moving back `lists.old` to its former name:

```
sudo mv lists.old lists
```

This is assuming that there was no *directory* called `lists.old` to start with.  If there was, then the `lists` thing is located inside that directory and has to be moved out of it:

```
sudo mv lists.old/lists ./
```